# Make AJAX call on 20th second of every minute

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making an AJAX call in my code. What i want is to hit the AJAX call at 20th second of every minute. This is the AJAX request that i am making.

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        headers: { 'x-cyclops-ajax': 'yes' },
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
            var keys = Object.keys(data["histData"]);
            $( "#main-div" ).empty();
            for( var i=0; i< keys.length; i++) {
                chart.series[i].setData(data["histData"][keys[i]]["histFailure"], true);
                $('#main-div').append( '<div class="homepage-availability-inner-div"><h1 class="homepage-availability-text"> ' + keys[i] + ': <span class="dashboard-success">' + data["availData"][keys[i]] + ' </span> </h1></div>');
            }
            chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(data["histKeys"]);
            console.log("Data:" + JSON.stringify(data["availData"]));
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("Did not hit the AJAX call");
        }
    });
}, 5000);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: interval to 20000, and think that no good idea make an $.ajax under setinterval, because is asyncronous

Comment: It's perfectly valid to use async methods in `setInterval` BTW, this is called long polling. though bear in mind that the responses may not come back in order

Comment: What exactly is the question here? Does this not work? What?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean only on the 20th second as in 13:00:**20**, 13:01:**20** , 13:02:**20**, ...

you would have to do something like this:

```js
// the interval can be set lower depending on the use case, to be more accurate
// Warning a too low interval setting might kill the performance of the browser/client, 
// and execute the ajax multiple times, if the milliseconds are not considerate 
let interval = 1000;

// the function is called (about) every second, 
// so approximately 60 times per minute and executes the ajax call only once. 
setInterval(
  function(){
    let now = new Date();

    // should only fire, if it is the 20th Second in the current minute
    if(now.getSeconds() === 20){
      //ajax call
      console.info(now);
    }
  }, interval 
);
```

The Code check every Second, if it is the 20th Second. The performance might be a bit heavy for the client, doing some many calls, but it works.

**Just to think about:**
*It could be optimized with changing the inertval, after a hit or higher interval length, or using `setTimeout` instead, and calculating, the next time to call it self.*

**btw.:**
*If you want to get the milliseconds also, you would have to put the interval lower and also query the `getMilliseconds()` function of the `now` Variable, but this would probably kill the performance of the client.*

- here is the link to the relevant [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getSeconds) to the `Date` function `getSeconds`
- here is a [explanation on how/why the timeout/interval is not accurate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified), but there are also other reasons.

**Optional (just4fun):**
If you want do less `setInterval` calls, you could use `setTimeout` and call the function recursively, the "problem" being, how to tweak the time setting to get close to the 20th seconds without missing it.

Here is a small basic example, to start from:
*(Yes the code isn't very optimized, and could be better structured, but I hope it gives a rough idea)*

```js
// the 20th Second, when the ajax call should execute
const selectedSecond = 20;

// can be tweaked to hit closer to 20th Second (ms)
let shortInterval = 400;

// depence on the size less calls are made
let safetyBuffer = 2;

// helper Variable, 60 Seconds
let sixtySeconds =  60;

// timeout value which is set dynamic, first time will execute "immediately"
let currentTimeout = 0;

function timeoutHandler(){
     // gets current Time
     let now = new Date();
     let seconds = now.getSeconds();
     if(seconds === selectedSecond){
        // **** here the ajax call should go ****
        console.info("ajax Called!!");
        // sets the next timeout 58s later, not to miss the 20th Second
        currentTimeout = (sixtySeconds - safetyBuffer) * 1000;
     }else if(seconds > selectedSecond){
        // sets the next timeout to 2s beforethe 20th Second
        currentTimeout = (sixtySeconds - safetyBuffer - seconds + selectedSecond) * 1000;
     } else if(seconds < selectedSecond - safetyBuffer) {
        // sets the next timeout to 2s beforethe 20th Second
        currentTimeout = (selectedSecond - safetyBuffer - seconds) * 1000;
     } else {
        // sets the next timeout to shortInterval(=400ms), 
        // for the last 2s, it will be more often, to not miss the 20th second
        currentTimeout = shortInterval;
     }
     
     // calls the function with the new optimized timeout
     setTimeout(timeoutHandler, currentTimeout);      
}

// initial call
setTimeout(timeoutHandler, currentTimeout);
```

Comment: Bear in mind this will not run on the 20th second **exactly**. `setInterval` is not guaranteed to run in the time period exactly. It will vary based on many factors, such as js thread usage, etc. So this will vary (likely quite a bit)

Comment: You are wright, but depending on the accuracy needed, I would put the interval lower, or try a different approche. I implied it is a web-application, where, there are no longrunning blocking JS-Scripts running, so it should be okay. But it depends on the use case

Comment: @Liam So my use case is that i have to refresh the page every minute on the 20th second. But what if a request is made and the data hasn't come back yet and the next request goes?

Comment: And will the time be 1000 or 60000?

Comment: @NikhilTikoo a new request would be send. What do you want, that should happen? And if the request takes longer than 1 Minute, you should optimize the service, since usually if no data is streamed in that 1 Minute, the connection would timeout.

Comment: Understood the point. But still confused about the time interval you have given. Should it be 1000 or 60000? Since i want the call to run every 60 seconds.

Comment: interval should be 1000. you want to check every Second, if it reached the 20th Second. :-D

Comment: OK i understood why you have the time interval as 1000. :)
Let me try this solution.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use setInterval method for continuous loop and when current second is 20 you can make ajax call. Please see the code snippet:

```
setInterval(function() {
  if(new Date().getSeconds() === 20) {
     // Your ajax call
  }
}, 1000);
```